# Edit answer adding source link

Tags: discussion, edits

I edited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14406172/552175) answer, which contains quite a bit of quoted text. While the answer does credit the source, it was not very specific, containing just the company name.

I added an exact link to the source and my edit was approved. But 2 out of 5 reviewers voted to reject the edit using the following reason: "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."

Later the author himself reverted my edit. So I'm wondering if adding source links in edits like I did is ok or not.

Comment: I think if it would be a community wiki then it would be okay. But here i would have wrote a comment to OP otherwise i think it's a conflict with the content of OP's original answer

Comment: Note that typically when people refer to "mods", they are talking about the [17 diamond moderators](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) and the Stack Exchange employees. These users just have more reputation that allows them to review edits.

Comment: A block quote that large should definitely attribute its source.

Comment: @Rizier123: How does it "conflict with the content of the OP's answer"? And what does community wiki have to do with it? Q&As are collaboratively edited and this edit did not change the substance of the post at all anyway.

Comment: I'm the original author. The source was an email from Xilinx, not this link. I was not aware of the availability of this information elsewhere.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, your edit was absolutely sound. The original post author *should* have included the link.

I cannot for the life of me comprehend why those two reviewers rejected your edit (but I see all sorts of bizarre review decisions, so it's not a big surprise), or why the author reverted it.

Comment: I'm the original author. I reverted the answer because my source was an email from Xilinx. I don't know know why the other reviewers rejected the edit. I have since updated the answer to more clearly state the source was an email, and then also to include the link added in the edit as well.